# Merge tags [international] and [international-law]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) and [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) each have 5 questions, and seem to cover the same kind of topics.

Should [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) questions be retagged into [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international)?

The "-law" suffix would probably apply to any tag on this site, so better not have it, I would say.

Answer (score 5):

I actually prefer [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law).

The word "law" is not automatically appended to all of our tags. For example, we should still have [criminal-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criminal-law), [corporate-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-law) etc., where as we have tags for countries (e.g. [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)) and concepts (e.g. [freedom-of-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedom-of-speech)).

The tag [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) is confusing. [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) is certainly the better-sounding option.

Answer (score 5):

The two tags are different in meaning; at the very least, several of the questions there should not have the [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) tag, and others should.

As I understand it, [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) could be for questions about how things are handled around the world. This is possibly too broad for this site; questions like that should be narrowed, and the tag could be removed. On the other hand, [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) should be for questions about *international law*: treaties, conventions, the UN, and similar things, including maybe "which countries have jurisdiction in these cases". Only two of the [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) questions are about that ([Which jurisdiction applies in a vessel?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/232/which-jurisdiction-applies-in-a-vessel) and [Claiming my own country](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/583/claiming-my-own-country)). [Restrictions on international data storage?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/481/restrictions-on-international-data-storage) shouldn't have the [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) tag.

We should certainly not put treaties under [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international); that's not the term used to describe them. The "law" suffix doesn't apply to all tags by any stretch of the imagination, and even if it *did* we should use the phrase that someone would actually use instead of trying a this-site-specific contraction. For another example of where "-law" makes a *massive* difference, [corporate-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-law) covers a subset of what [corporate](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate) might cover, because lots of stuff involving corporations isn't "corporate law".

Comment: This is undoubtedly right, and defines the difference between subject and jurisdictional tags.

Answer (score -1):

I would say yes, [international](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) should be the tag we go with.