# The [contract] and [contract-law] tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Currently, we have both [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract) and [contract-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-law).

They both seem to deal with the body of law, but they're not all on the same questions.

We can:

- Leave it as it is if we can find some difference in usage
- Merge and synonymise them if they are being used for the same purpose

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's *possible* to make a distinction.  E.g., [contract-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-law) could be about the laws that govern the interpretation and limitations of contracts in general, while [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract) would for questions about contracts themselves.

An example of [contract-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-law): Is a contract that involves illegal actions enforceable?

An example of [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract): Is it possible to [use a contract to indemnify duelers](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1710/10)?

But, as we can see here, the distinction is very hard to discern because the principles of the former almost always inform answers to the latter.

Therefore: We should synonymize these, and, following **@cpast's rule**<sup>1</sup> make [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract) a synonym for [contract-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-law).

---

<sup>1</sup>[Use the phrase that someone would actually use instead of trying a this-site-specific contraction](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/146/10).