# The [contract] and [contract-law] tags, seven years later

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

In 2015, [a suggestion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/236/44937) to merge [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract) and [contract-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-law) got three upvotes and no downvotes, but seven years later, we still have separate tags. Is it time to merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These were [merged as synonyms circa 20/08/2022](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

No doubt a Mod will be along soon to tag this as [status-completed](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).